# How to select certain parts of a JSON file using python?

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to programming, how would I select a certain part of the JSON file and have it display the value? For example:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 18,
  "state": "New York"
}
```

What would be the code in Python needed to get the value of any of the items by giving it the keyword? (i.e. I give it "name" and the output displays  "John")

Comment: What NumberC neglects to mention is anything about why that code works - your JSON example is a dictionary, and that’s how dictionary elements are accessed. So in the case `”name”` is a key and `”John”` is the value for that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the title in brackets.

```
myJSON = #that JSON
print(myJSON["name"]) #prints John
print(myJSON["age"]) #prints 18
print(myJSON["state"]) #prints New York
```

Comment: An explanation of why this works would be good/helpful.

Comment: @barny I don't understand what you mean by why this works? It's just the syntax. It's just the way it is.

Comment: What sort of data structure is myJSON? If it were a list that syntax wouldn’t work, would it? The OP clearly doesn’t know what sort of data structure his json is.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, you didn't specify. No need to be so aggresive. The data structure of the JSON, at least based on the question, is a dictionary.